# Weird usage of "jed- einzeln"

Tags: article

> Ich erzähle das jedem Patienten einzeln.

I find this sentence quite weird. I think it should be like this:

> Ich erzähle das jedem einzelnen Patienten.

Can you please give me other examples of this combination "jed- + Nomen + einzeln"?

Comment: What do you consider weird? That’s just two different meanings.

Comment: "Weird" is an all-purpose tag in youth-speech. Like "awesome". @Stephie

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your two sentences are not interchangeable and do not mean the same thing.

*einzeln* is an adjective, and in your second example, used as such.

Your first example, however, applies *einzeln* in **adverbial** usage, thus qualifies the predicate of the sentence instead of the object.

Let's explain that in English, where you can do the same thing

> I am telling that every individual patient

I simply make sure every individual patient gets to know the fact - we could even fill a classroom with patients, and the sentence would still apply.

> I am telling that every patient individually

applies the "individual" to the predicate and thus excludes the classroom case. It means a separate face-to-face action.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of your "English" sentences are wrong. You need to say "that to every...."

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of those two sentences is different. In the second case, every single patient is told something:

> Ich erzähle das jedem einzelnen Patienten.

> I tell that to every single patient.

Here, "einzeln" gives further emphasis to "jedem". You're not only telling every patient, but every single patient.

In the first case, "einzeln" means more something like "separate":

> Ich erzähle das jedem Patienten einzeln.

> I tell that to every patient separately / individually.

Here, the adverb "einzeln" further characterizes the predicate (*how* are you telling every patient? - You're telling them separately).

An example with another adverb would be:

> Ich sage das jedem lauten Patienten.

> I tell that to every loud patient.

in constrast to

> Ich sage das jedem Patienten laut.

> I tell that to every patient loudly.